# Program to compare two files line by line

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there a GUI-based program on Ubuntu that compares two files line by line and indicates where two lines do not match? If not, any console app that does the same thing?

Answer (score 6):

- meld
- tkdiff
- vim

meld is -my- favorite.

Console has a command for it:
diff {file1} {file2}

Comment: Wow!  Meld is now also my favourite!